# Using JSON in server vs Database (Pros/Cons)

Tags: node.js, json, database, server

I don't know whether we allow to ask this kind of questions but, I need some suggestions.

**What I have**

I am creating a dataset in a JSON format which will be around 3.5 to 5 mb. 
In this single json there are 5k - 10k objects with 20 fields.

**How am I going to use this dataset**

Basically, I will render particular object in a specific page.

www.site.com/:id (GET)

Sort according to one of the object's field and render top 100 list (show 5 fields of that object in one row for example)

www.site.com/list?sort_by={field_name} (GET)

**Question**

Do I need to create a noSQL database or can I put this json in my server and directly reach that database in backend ? 
I have never done this kind of thing but I am thinking for this project because dataset will always be the same (static) I always need to read that data (no POST, PUT, DELETE etc) This is why having json on server makes sense to me but I wanted to ask whether I am missing something.

Also I don't know so much thing about bandwidths or how networks work. In this approach, we won't send this 5 mb file to the client right ? (Even the client needs to have only one object inside whole array which has 10k objects)

Or do we have any performance issues in our server ? Because if I put this json in server, I will use it like:

```
let data = require('./data/main.json')

app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    const obj = data.find(d => d.id === id)
    res.status(200).json(obj)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a database has additional benefits, such as the ability to easily create backups of your file, access the database from additional devices, and provide analytics. While you can use a JSON file in your case, I highly recommend using [MongoDB](https://mongodb.com) as a NoSQL database and [mongoose](https://npmjs/org/package/mongoose) as an ORM. It's basically like working with JSON but definitely a much better experience and better in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongodb or Mongoose to do that, because mongo is basically store your data as json format, the benefits is that json is very fast to read, and very easy to handle and use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know and I always use mongo as a NoSql db but my question was what if I don't use any db, do I harm my system ? Your message unfortunately is answering another question.